# Forms data to Database using PHP and Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

Hitting a brick wall with this issue. I have everything setup as below, and the issue is when I hit my submit button I get a "Page not found" error. Can anyone see my error?

Here is my Registration.html

```
<form name="submission" action="test_connection.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br>
     <input type="text" name="lastname" />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my test_connection.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("myInternalHostname","username","password","databaseName");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Accounts (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've tried using the website name instead of the database hostname. I've tried changing the "action=" to include the full path in server (domains/websiteName/html/wp-content/themes/themeName/test_connection.php) but I still receive the "Page not found" error. From the solutions I've seen in other sources it always had to deal with naming conventions. But I'm convinced there's a problem with Wordpress and it finding/running the PHP file. I just can't see how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is your test_connection.php file available directly? I.e. without using forms.

Comment: You should double-check the accuracy of the path in your form's action attribute.

Comment: @SlavaFominII how would I check this if the files are being hosted by a service?

Comment: @Nathan what do you mean by "service"? Try to invoke this file directly with your browser.

Comment: @SlavaFominII I mean that all the files are hosted by MediaTemple. However I did try to access the page directly and it did not work. I get a "page not found" webpage on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this. Had to install a plugin for WordPress to make the PHP work.

[Insert PHP](http://www.willmaster.com/software/WPplugins/)

Once installed I was able to change the action attribute to

`action="[insert_php] echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/test-connection.php[/insert_php]"`

If you also notice in code above, I also changed to file name from `test_connection.php` to `test-connection.php`. Don't know if that made any difference, but I had read that this was a better naming convention.

Hopes this helps anyone else looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass this in your action,

test_connection.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Hope this helps you

Comment: I don't see what you added. This is exactly how I currently have my action command setup.

Comment: action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/test_connection.php". add this

Comment: No Chinju that did not work. It actually messed up the first name field. It's not showing on the page now.

Comment: Then why dont you try with Wordpress default Insert query.? It would be better I think @Nathan